# Setting a unique client-id on a Kafka Sink Connector

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to use JMX to monitor a set of connector tasks running on a distributed worker. The only usable JMX output seems to be the Kafka Consumer MBeans. Unfortunately, setting an identifiable `client.id` on the Kafka Consumer being used by the worker task seems impossible.

The documentation suggests to use `client.id` on the [connector configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectconfigs). Setting this on the connector configuration has no effect. Setting this on the worker configuration (properties file) only sets this for use by the worker for configuration and status topics.

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/dd71e4a8d830c9de40b5ec3f987f60a1d2f26b39/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/WorkerSinkTask.java#L388) it seems the sink consumer uses the worker configuration with a prefix `consumer.`. Doing this works, but this is a single client-id set across all tasks in the worker, making monitoring a single consumer, or even a specific connector impossible.

The default behavior will use the default `client.id` in the consumer, which is to use `consumer-n`, where `n` is an incremented number. The JMX output does not include the `groupd.id` that this consumer is part of, so it makes it impossible to correlate the consumer connection with a connector running in that worker.

Without additional JMX output (like `groupd.id` and connector name), or a better default `client.id` I can't see how I can monitor Kafka Connectors using JMX.

Comment: A workaround to the unique client.id issue for JMX identification is to query the broker for group membership and leave the default consumer id in the connectors. Not ideal, as you need to keep track of group membership separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think there's a bit of confusion about where settings go. There are two types of configuration: Corker and Connector. There are a small number of configs that can be used in both (e.g. allowing default worker-level configs to be overridden per connector), but for the most part they are distinct: worker level configs control how the entire process operates, whereas connector configs are specific to the individual connector.

Logically, a single Connect cluster will be operating many clients which you might want to treat independently, which I think is what your question is getting at. The types of clients include source tasks (producers), sink tasks (consumers), as well as the framework level client (Worker).

The first link you gave is for Kafka Connect *worker* configuration. The `client.id` appears there because Workers coordinate with each other via the same group coordination protocol that consumers use. So the `client.id` you would specify in the Worker config would be something like `my-kafka-connect-cluster-worker` indicating the traffic associated with the *Worker* operations is associated with a Connect cluster's worker.

You are correct that you can override the `consumer.client.id` (or really any producer or consumer config) and it will apply, across the board, to all clients created in that worker. But as you correctly note, this will be uniform.

The short answer is that at the moment this will not be easy to override, although the fix should be trivial (and definitely worth making). The code that [creates producers](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/Worker.java#L362) and [creates consumers](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/WorkerSinkTask.java#L371-L394) should be using at least the worker group ID and task ID to generate a default client ID and adding that to the configuration (the combination of the 2 guarantees a unique ID even if you run multiple connect clusters against the same Kafka cluster).

There's a [JIRA filed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5061) for addressing this issue.

Comment: Thanks Ewen. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

As of Apache Kafka 2.3 and [KIP-411](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-411%3A+Make+default+Kafka+Connect+worker+task+client+IDs+distinct) the `client.id` is set to be the connector ID + task, as seen here for a single connector with three tasks consuming a topic with ten partitions:

```
$ docker exec -it kafka kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:29092 --describe --group connect-sink-elastic-orders-00-A

GROUP                            TOPIC    PARTITION  CLIENT-ID 
connect-sink-elastic-orders-00-A orders2  0          connector-consumer-sink-elastic-orders-00-A-0 
connect-sink-elastic-orders-00-A orders2  1          connector-consumer-sink-elastic-orders-00-A-0 
connect-sink-elastic-orders-00-A orders2  2          connector-consumer-sink-elastic-orders-00-A-0 
connect-sink-elastic-orders-00-A orders2  3          connector-consumer-sink-elastic-orders-00-A-0 
connect-sink-elastic-orders-00-A orders2  4          connector-consumer-sink-elastic-orders-00-A-1 
connect-sink-elastic-orders-00-A orders2  5          connector-consumer-sink-elastic-orders-00-A-1 
connect-sink-elastic-orders-00-A orders2  6          connector-consumer-sink-elastic-orders-00-A-1 
connect-sink-elastic-orders-00-A orders2  7          connector-consumer-sink-elastic-orders-00-A-2 
connect-sink-elastic-orders-00-A orders2  8          connector-consumer-sink-elastic-orders-00-A-2 
connect-sink-elastic-orders-00-A orders2  9          connector-consumer-sink-elastic-orders-00-A-2
```

*(some columns dropped for readability)*